# Cannot use typedefs inherited from std::unary_function

Tags: c++

```
prog.cpp:9:13: error: ‘result_type’ does not name a type
prog.cpp:9:13: note: (perhaps ‘typename std::unary_function<_Arg, _Result>::result_type’ was intended)
```

Compiler:
http://ideone.com/vttG8W

Why cannot I use result_type directly?

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template <typename ARGUEMENT, typename RESULT>
class FunctorBase : public std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>
{
public:
    virtual result_type operator () (argument_type) = 0;
        FunctorBase() {}
        virtual ~FunctorBase() {}
};

int main()
{
    FunctorBase<int&, void>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is an *unqualified name*.

When you use unqualified names in a class template, you have to tell the compiler that it should not immediately search for global names during the first phase of the two-phase name lookup, but rather wait until instantiation (because the name could come from a base class, as is the case here).

In this case, you could do this (and make `result_type` a *dependent*, qualified name):

```
typedef typename std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>::result_type result_type;
```

Notice that the same applies to `argument_type`.

```
typedef typename std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>::argument_type argument_type;
```

Armed with those two `typedef`s, the original member function declaration will now compile:

```
virtual result_type operator () (argument_type) = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `result_type` and `argument_type` depend on the template parameters. Use:

```
virtual typename std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>::result_type
  operator () (typename std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>::argument_type) = 0;
```

or, if you need it in more places, add

```
using typename std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>::result_type;
using typename std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>::argument_type;
```

in the beginning of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-typedef it in your class:

```
typedef typename std::unary_function<ARGUEMENT, RESULT>::result_type my_result_type;
```

(You can even rename it the exact same thing)
This is can work even if what you inherit from is private.

This [compiles](http://ideone.com/nXas0C):

```
template <typename blah>
class MyTemplateBaseClass
{
    public: 
    typedef blah my_blah_typedef;
};

template <typename arg>
class DerivedFromTemplated : private MyTemplateBaseClass<arg>
{
public:
    //Either giving the full name:
    typename MyTemplateBaseClass<arg>::my_blah_typedef GetBlahType()
    {
        return typename MyTemplateBaseClass<arg>::my_blah_typedef();
    }

    //Or typedef-ing it locally:
    typedef typename MyTemplateBaseClass<arg>::my_blah_typedef my_blah_typedef;
    my_blah_typedef GetBlahType2()
    {
        return my_blah_typedef();
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedFromTemplated<int> test;
}
```

Comment: The first line says `typedef template ...` instead of `typedef typename ...`.

Comment: Whoops. The one line I didn't test compile, is the one with a simple mistake. =)
Thanks for pointing it out.